# $_POST всегда пустой, хотя в file_get_contents('php://input') есть данные

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

Пытаюсь отправить данные формы при помощи fetchAPI. Вот форма:

```js
const regUserBtn = document.getElementById('regUser');
regUserBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData = getRegFormData(regForm);
  try {
    let response = fetch('/index/registerUser', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        redirect: 'follow',
        referrer: 'no-referrer',
        body: formData,
      })
      .then(response => response.json());

    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Ошибка:', error);
  }
});

function getRegFormData(regForm) {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('email', regForm.email.value);
  formData.append('firstName', regForm.firstName.value);
  formData.append('secondName', regForm.secondName.value);
  formData.append('password', regForm.password.value);

  return formData;
}
```

```html
<div id="signup-tab-content" class="active">
  <form class="auth-form" id="regForm"  method="post" name="auth-form">
    <input type="email" required="" autocomplete="on" class="input" id="user_email" placeholder="Эл. адрес" name="email">
    <input type="text" required autocomplete="on" class="input" id="first-name" placeholder="Имя" name="firstName">
    <input type="text" class="input" autocomplete="on" id="second-name" placeholder="Фамилия" name="secondName">
    <input type="password" required class="input" id="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Пароль" name="password">

    <input id="regUser" type="submit" class="button" value="Регистрация">
  </form>
  <!--.login-form-->
</div>
<!--.signup-tab-content-->
```

А вот так я пытаюсь принять данные на сервере indexController.php:

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function register()
    {

        $requestPost = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

        return var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')); exit;

        die(json_encode($validetedData));
    }
}
```

При попытке взаимодействия переменная `$requestPost` всегда пустая, чтобы я не делал. `file_get_contents('php://input')` возвращает массив post, но через него нельзя фото загружать, а мне нужна эта функциональность.

Если я сделаю вот так:

```
$apiRequestArray = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
$requestPost = filter_var_array($apiRequestArray);
return $requestPost;
```

То в ответ js не получит ничего переменная response.json() будет пустая

если `die(json_encode([$requestPost]));`  то тоже, post-запрос зависнет, как pending. Не понимаю, в чем дело, не работает `return` из функции, хотя `var_dump` возвращает данные, их видно на вкладке network.

P.S возможно, все дело в моем самописном роутере, выглядит он вот так:

App.php

```
class App extends \app\core\Base
{
    public function dispatch()
    {
     $this->setController();

    $this->setMethod();

    $this->setParams();

    if (class_exists($this->controller)) {
        $controllerObject = new $this->controller();
        if (method_exists($controllerObject, $this->method)) {
            call_user_func_array([$controllerObject, $this->method], $this->params);
            } else {
                $this->respondNotFound();
            }
        } else {
            $this->respondNotFound();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parse the url into an array so we can access the indexes as a
     * controller, method and optional params.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function parseUrl()
    {
        $requestUri = rtrim(filter_input_array(INPUT_SERVER)['REQUEST_URI']);

        if (isset($requestUri) && !empty($requestUri)) {
            return explode('/', str_replace('.php', '', $requestUri));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the controller using the first index of the url.
     */
    private function setController()
    {
        array_shift($this->url);

        if (empty($this->url[0])) {
            $this->url[0] = 'index';
        }

        $path = str_replace('\\', '/', ROOT . '/dummyAdmin/app/controllers/' . $this->url[0] . 'Controller.php');

        if (file_exists($path)) {
            $this->controller = 'app\\controllers\\' . $this->url[0] . 'Controller';
            unset($this->url[0]);
        }
        else if (!file_exists($path) && !empty($this->url[0])) {
            $this->respondNotFound();
        }

        require_once $path;
    }

    /**
    * Set the method using the second index of the url.
    */
    private function setMethod()
    {
        if (isset($this->url[1]) && method_exists($this->controller, $this->url[1])) {
            $this->method = $this->url[1];
            unset($this->url[1]);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Set the params to pass to the controller method.
    *
    * Params equal the remaining values in the url array rebased.
    *
    * Additionally, we pass the $_POST super global for any optional
    * POST data
    */
    private function setParams()
    {
        $postRequest = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

        $this->params = $this->url ? [array_values($this->url), $postRequest] : [$postRequest];
    }
}
```

И потом в index.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use app\core\App;

$app = new App();
$app->dispatch();
```

Если дело в нем, то как это можно исправить? или он совсем никуда не годится и лучше совсем от него избавится и заменить на что то другое?

Comment: Попробуйте в JS поменять заголовок на: Content-Type: form/multipart

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис поменял, var_dump($_POST) по прежнему возвращает `array(0) {}`

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис я убрал `headers` совсем и `filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)` заработал) я стал получать post запросы, но я ничего не могу вернуть в ответ за мой запрос, return из функции register не делает ничего, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: return из метода register() у вас просто возвращает управление в dispatch() и всё, а dispatch ничего не возвращает.

Comment: А я могу как то изменить код функции dispatch, чтобы она могла возвращать данные? `return json_encode($this->params)` не помогло

Comment: Обычно вывод данных делают в конце контроллера (просто echo или ob_flush и т.д. если используется буфер). Если очень хочется делать это в роутере, то выводите возвращаемый результат от call_user_func_array, т.е. echo call_user_func_array

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис да, это действительно сработало, кажется) оформите, пожалуйста, это в ответ, чтобы я мог принять его)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В JavaScript'е надо убрать заголовок 'Content-Type': 'application/json', т.к. он не соответствует передаваемому Content-Type. А Content-Type: form/multipart подставится автоматически.
2. Чтобы вернуть ответ нужно использовать функции вывода (echo и т.д.), т.е. либо прописывать echo в конце контроллера, либо в роутере echo call_user_func_array(...)