# Как получить данные из реквеста пришедшие в json?

Tags: php, битрикс

Я разрабатываю платежный модуль.

Платежка делает callback запрос в случае успешной оплаты.
Платежка делает POST запрос. И передает данные в json

```
POST http://localhost/bitrix/tools/sale_ps_result.php
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "foo": "ok",
}
```

Как получить данные из реквеста?
Я знаю этот способ.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Может быть CMS имеет способ читать json из реквеста своим оброзом?

Comment: Чем вам $_POST не устроил? Объясните.

Comment: @Borislav
В $_POST парсяться данные отправленные ввиде `--data-urlencode`.
А не `application/json`.

Comment: JSON прилетает обьектом? Уточните,а? То ведь ничего не знаю. А то всяко от плюсиков и галочек так и пытаются отлынивать вопрошающие))
В данном случае
$result=$_POST;
$reult=$_REQUEST;

echo "<pre>"; print_r ($_POST); echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>"; print_r ($_REQUEST); echo "</pre>";

Comment: Даже не прошу развернутый вопрос, что на входе, что на выходе. А подсказал про функцию, входящую в ядро Битрикс , иначе ваш случай элементарно вписывается куда угодно, даже хоть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1043265/post-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%B2-file-get-contentsphp-input-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5

Answer (score 0):

Да, попадается иногда **\CUtil::JsObjectToPhp**

Вот например, навскидку написал:

```
class MyJSON extends CModule 
{

    public function __construct($strJSON)
    {
        $this->strJSON=$strJSON;
    }

    public function isJson($string)
    {
        json_decode($string);
        return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
    }


    private function query($url)
    {
        if($this->access_token === false)
            return false;

        $http = new HttpClient();
        $http->setHeader("authorization", "Bearer ".$this->access_token);
        $result = $http->get($url);

        if(!defined("BX_UTF"))
        {
            $result = CharsetConverter::ConvertCharset($result, "utf-8", LANG_CHARSET);
        }

        $result = CUtil::JsObjectToPhp($result);

        return $result;
    }       

    public function getDownloadToken()
    {
        $url = 'https://clou12d.mai1123l.ru/api/v2/tokens/download';

        $postData = ''
                . 'api=2'
                . '&build=' . $this->build
                . '&email=' . $this->user //. '%40mail.ru'
                . '&token=' . $this->token
                . '&x-email=' . $this->user //. '%40mail.ru'
                . '&x-page-id=' . $this->x_page_id;

        $result = $this->Post($url, $postData);
        if ($result !== 'error') {
            $result = \CUtil::JsObjectToPhp($result);
            if($result['body']['token'])
            {
                $this->downloadToken = $result['body']['token'];
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }   


}

var_dump(\MyJSON->isJson("{'key':'val'}"))
```

Comment: Ээ.... может быть я не очевидно описал вопрос. Но я не делаю запрос в стороний сервис а принимаю POST запрос. В котором данные передаються в формате json

Comment: $result в данном случае $_REQUEST  
echo "<pre>"; print_r ($_REQUEST); echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>"; print_r ($_POST); echo "</pre>";
Уточните, декодируются данные с JSON?